# Problem in functional analysis: application of open mapping theorem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm having trouble in exercise 2.10 in Brezis' book in Functional Analysis: let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces and let $T \in \cal{L}$$(E,F)$ be surjective. Let $M$ be any subset of $E$. Prove that $T(M)$ is closed in $F$ iff $M+N(T)$ is closed in $E$.

I was able to prove that $M+N(T)$ is closed in $F$ if $T(M)$ is closed in $E$ by noting that $$M+N(T) = T^{-1}(T(M))$$ and using the fact that $T$ is continuous. For the other part, my idea was to prove that $$(T(M))^{c} = T((M+N(T))^{c})$$ and then use the open mapping theorem. However, I can only prove that $$(T(M))^{c} \subset T((M+N(T))^{c}),$$ for the other inclusion it seems that I need $T$ to also be injetive, so I guess this method does not work. Am I missing something here, or is there a better way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M+N(T)$ is closed, its complementary subspace $U$ is open, since $T$ is surjective, the open map theorem implies that $T(U)$ is open, but $T(U)$ is the complementary of $T(M)$, thus $T(M)$ is closed.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but why is $T(U)$ the complement of $T(M)$? Wouldn't $T$ have to be injective for that to be true? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It has to be rather surjective. Remark that $M+N(T)=T^{-1}(T(M))$, let $v\in T(U)\cap T(M), v=T(u), u\in U$, this implies that $T(u)\in T(M)$, thus $u\in T^{-1}(T(M))=M+N(T)$ contradiction. Thus $T(U)\subset T(M)^c$. On the other hand. Let $v\in T(M)^c$, since $T$ is surjective, there exists $u\in E$ such that $T(u)\in V$, suppose that $u\in M+N(T)$, $T(u)\in T(M)\cap T(M)^c$ contradiction, thus $u\in (M+N(T))^c=U$, thus $T(M)^c=T(U)$

Comment: Ok, I got it. I had proved that $M+N(T) = T^{-1}(T(M))$ but I wasn't thinking about using it on the other part of the problem. Thank you very much!